# Supressing the Confirm box in an access vba function

Tags: ms-access

I've got an Access database and in there I have macro which outputs a query to a csv file ready for import into another system we are using.  As part of this macro it makes a backup of the base table and then later changes the contents of the original table.  When it does the backup, I get a dialog box asking me to confirm that I want to overwrite the old backup table.

I don't want this dialog box coming up because the macro will be run by an end user eventually.  I'm using

DoCmd.CopyObject to do this.  Is there a way I can supress this dialog box?

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: Have you tried `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`?